# Waiting until an application is reading (over a TTY)

Tags: linux, terminal, pipe, tty, expect

I'm writing an expect-style program to interact with a command-line application on Linux. Is there any way that my program can know when the application on the other side of the PTY tries to perform a `read` over it?

Ideally, this would be possible without knowing what processes are running on the other side of the PTY (or with only knowledge of the process group). Polling the state of the ptmx file descriptor doesn't work, since I'm always *able* to write to it, even if that write will be buffered internally by the kernel.

Comment: `expect` does not try to guess when the application it monitors does a read, but instead have actions when the application it monitors does some specific writes (a prompt, an error message, etc). Why do you need to guess the read? isn't there any prompt before it?

Comment: And a very different approach is possible : if you own both process and can modify them : the monitoring program could receive a signal from the monitored application when that application starts to read? ( ex: SIGUSR1 (10 on linux)) and the monitoring program have a trap defined on that signal, that then starts the appropriate functions (and maybe re-installs itself) ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately, I don't own both processes, or even know how many processes might exist, so adding a user signal is out of the question.  
  
Supposing I did know their PIDs, though, would there be a way to monitor the processes to find out when they're blocking on I/O?  
  
The end goal is something more general -- an interface to run shell commands, where I'd like to be able to only prompt for user input when an application wants it. This experiment is a first step in figuring out what's feasible.

Comment: This is really nontrivial to do, especially taking into account other types of operations such as querying if there's pending incoming data (rather than trying to read). You might want to trace the process in question, or have an LD_PRELOAD wrapper that overwrites the behavior of the `read()`/`fread()` families. Expect this to be quite a complex programming and debugging task, nowhere near as straightforward as you're probably hoping for.

Comment: @Subhav : with the process(es) pid known, you could maybe invoke a : strace on it (or other equivalent system calls monitoring tools, strace is old), and monitor that (with the proper filtering to avoir bandwidth bottlenecks : just make it show the exact function call(s) you are looking for, for exemple). I do that manually to find out if a process "loops" or hangs on something (I found an AIX (now-fixed) bug where sometimes a telnet invoking via ssh wouldn't close properly and loop, becoming a 100% cpu process until killed : truss (the strace on aix) allowed me to file a proper bug report)